# Item's content layout breaks when dragging

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cdk

I've used @angular/cdk/drag-drop library to implement a drag and drop functionality. It works well, however when dragging an element, the layout of dragged item (div containing mat-angular dropdowns, delete icon and drag handle) breaks.

As soon as I place the item it is back in place looking as it should (img 1), but it looks like during dragging the item loses its parent div, therefore it is not inline, as well as not retaining the same dimensions (img 2)

[image]
This is how it looks before dragging

[image]
This is how it looks during dragging

I've attempted to solve this with adding a class with required width and height + set its display property to inline flex, however it does not help.